# Postfix Mail Server on Webmin. Failed to connect to server, permission denied(13)

Tags: smtp, phpmailer, postfix-mta, webmin

I used PHPMailer to send out email and it work perfectly fine on localhost. However, as client requested, we have to upload everything onto webmin. The PostFix Mail Server was being installed for us. The problem is that I could not get the email function to work on the server.

Here are my codes.

```
<?php
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body = 'Test Email';

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                       // 1 = errors and messages
                                       // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "smtp.xxx.xxx.xx";
$mail->Port       = 25;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "";
$mail->Password   = "";
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tsl';

$mail->SetFrom('support@xxx.xxx', 'Support');

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic with authentication";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "xxx@hotmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "Sara Chan");

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Message sent!";
}

?>
```

**Error message:**
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Permission denied (13) SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.

I have tried configuring the postfix main.cf file, but it still does not work. 
I've tried:

1. http://postfix.state-of-mind.de/patrick.koetter/smtpauth/postfix_configuration.html
2. http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html
3. http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix
4. http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#null_client

Configuration from these links are different. I'm a new PHP programmer (Still an undergraduate student), and all these are really confusing. Right now, my postfix main.cf is back to its 'default' state. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using an old version of PHPMailer, so [update that](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

If you're sending from the same server as your script (which it sounds like you are since you're configuring postfix), don't use SMTP, call the `IsMail()` or `IsSendmail()` function instead of `IsSMTP()`.

There's no such SMTP secure mode as 'tsl' - you're thinking of 'tls', and if you were going to use that it would probably be on port 587 rather than 25.

You won't need to supply auth credentials if you're sending via mail or sendmail.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on a Oracle Linux 7.7 server and **solved** it by entering the following commands:

> sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail 1
>   sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1